# "There is" vs. "there are" when contracted

Tags: grammaticality, contractions

Unless I am mistaken, when referring to a single thing or entity, one can say `there is` or `there's` (the contraction of the same). When referring to more than one of something, the correct wording is `there are`, however, I am not aware of an actual contraction of the latter, or `there're`.

As a native speaker, it seems perfectly fine to hear (and to use) `there's` in place of `there are` (at least for some examples, but I can't think of any that *really* don't work), but is this a valid grammatical usage?

e.g.

> There are many ways this can be stated.
>
> There's many ways this can be stated.

Am I wrong in accepting this? Should I try to break myself of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an informal usage, but many native speakers have no problem at all with constructions like...

> [There's two ways this can go](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22There%27s%20two%20ways%22&aq=f&oq=%22There%27s%20two%20ways%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.50564746j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

...even though they would balk at the full form *There **is** two ways this can go*.

By traditional rules of grammar, obviously, it's "incorrect". But in the contracted form it's perfectly normal in informal speech. I don't think anyone would be pedantic enough to suggest you should get out of the habit of using a natural form you're quite comfortable with.

Answer (score 4):

*There’re* is an attested contraction (and a word that I personally use). Like *there’s*, it is used in informal contexts. For definition and examples of its use, see the *[OneLook](http://onelook.com/?w=there%27re&ls=a)* entry.

Answer (score 4):

Once a form is contracted, it starts getting glued together and agreement phenomena affect it less and less, until you have something frozen like *ain't* or *wanna*.

*There*, since it is a dummy, has no meaning, just a function -- to indicate that there's a noun phrase to pay attention to coming after the verb. *There* is neither singular nor plural, so the question of the auxiliary is problematic, since it has to be pronounced **before** the noun phrase it might have to agree with. This causes problems.

So, what happens is that, since the subject and the verb are both meaningless and predictable, there's no real reason to worry about the official number of a contracted auxiliary verb with a dummy subject.  And, therefore, in speech (i.e, real language), many people are comfortable with *there's* in both singular and plural.

Not to say that *there're* doesn't occur; but [it's less common](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/54754/15299), if only because it's an extra syllable, which is unwelcome in a contraction.

Comment: I don't know how it is pronounced elsewhere, but my pronunciation is monosyllabic with nothing more than a bit of extended "r" sound to distinguish it from "there".

Comment: If you're speaking fast, that means you're distinguishing between a long and a short rhoticized shwa in totally unstressed position in the middle of a consonant cluster. Get thee to a sociophonetician and get it recorded. BTW, I have no doubt you perceive this, as a speaker; but you can sense your tongue and others can only hear it, so there may well be some variation in others' perception of what you're saying. Just sayin'.

Comment: The difference between "there" and "there're" is about a fifth of a second of "r".

Comment: Be interesting to test listeners on discrimination.

Comment: I would bet against it. It's probably clear only from context.

Comment: @MετάEd, John: Based on how I've seen people react to [prints/prince](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=35322), I suspect those who can spell habitually harbour illusions over what phonetic distinctions they make - or more correctly, *don't* make, particularly in [casual] speech. And I know that as a *listener* I personally don't tend to hear variations that have no semantic significance.

Answer (score 2):

I also use *there're*; the only thing I'd add is that while *there's* would be considered by most a perfectly “normal" contraction, although informal, I think that *there're* would strike most people as somewhat “non-standard" and certainly much more informal.

Comment: I would definitely say, for example, "There're two ways to look at it."  The double-R sound is sort of a weak trill.