# "There's bells"- is that grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I was at my house and I was looking at a new one-hundred-dollar bill that had a blue thing running through it. Then my mom asked me what it was for and I said "If you look at it a certain way there's bells." Then my dad "corrected" me and said "there are bells". Was my statement grammatically correct? Almost everyone around me uses "there's" as in "there's people there" or "there's goats."(I live in Indiana by the way). Are these statements grammatically correct? Was my statement grammatically correct? Why or why not?

Comment: Yes it is grammatical. [Once a contraction is made, it can't be unmade](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/110030/15299), and _there's_ is the usual contraction.

Comment: When enough people are wrong, they are right...

Comment: Since bells don't live on bills, their image does, you're saying there's [an image of] bells at that angle. Now we can sleep.